# Creating and Editing related entities from a ASP.NET MVC web form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I'm creating a ASP.NET MVC 4 web app with a database and Entity Framework 5 for a web form to maintain Document (aka Contract) entries.

Below is a sample ERD (in the form of edmx diagram with navigational properties) I have created for a DB in SQL server. For MVC web app the Model is generated from the DB with .edmx file.

[image]

Based on the Model, I have setup a form which can create and edit a Document like so:
[image]

**Document Create and Edit View**

This view refers to Document model class. So all the input fields using html helper (Html.TextBoxFor...,etc) are referred from Document object and its related objects (Section 1 & Section 2). The checkbox hides and shows the subform for a section with JS/jQuery. For the Edit view I use same as Create view, except it contains additional hidden ID fields to identity the records to edit from the DB.
I have added a variable length list for section item addition by following this:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/
In the partial view for the items dynamic list I use Section1Item and Section2Item as model reference.

**Document Controller's Create method** 
So on Create the document object posted in Create(...) method contains all the attributes from the Document including the section's attributes. 
If the checkbox value for Section 1 & Section 2 are false then I set the Document's Section 1 & Section 2 to null like so:

```
if (section1_chkbox == false) {
   document.Section1 = null; 
}
```

I have to add each item from the dynamic list into the document object like so:

```
foreach(Section1Item item in itemsList) {
   document.Section1.Section1Items.Add(item);
}
```

So finally the Create method in the DocumentController adds the document in a db context and saves changes. The document and its related entities are successfully added to database tables.

**Document Controller's Edit method**

But when I'm editing the document with the Edit method in DocumentController there are some inconsistencies with some section1 object's ID being null for some related objects in Section1Items. For example when Section1Items are present the posted Document object (for edit) does not contain reference to Section 1 object's ID.
So it is fiddly and messy to update an existing document record as I'm having to check the ID attributes of a object. There are always errors like inconsistent principal and dependent objects in the relationship when saving or setting the object's entry state to modified.

**My Question**

How can I setup the View and Controller to achieve a functioning Create and Edit of a document along with its related entities as in the form's interface able? I need a efficient and correct way to use Entity Framework for this. How can I use view models for this if that would make this easier?

Comment: Please add your edit action method to show the object you send along to the view and the view controls

Answer (score 0):

From what you described here I understand that there is a problem with virtual reference to Section1 from Section1Items. So in other words the problem is that entity framework model doesn't suit you display needs. You would need to render duplicated entities to map entier Document in your view. Am I right?

If that's the case I see two solutions:

- like you suggested use view models to solve the problem. If you confirm the issue I can try to write example view model.
- serialzie/encrypt entier Document in your view and next merge edited result with encrypted Document. You can achive that by using [Mvc3Futures](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Mvc3Futures/) feature.

Serialize and encrypt your document in view:

```
@Html.Serialize("Document", Model, SerializationMode.EncryptedAndSigned)
```

And to deserialzie and decrypt you can use:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id,[Deserialize(SerializationMode.EncryptedAndSigned)]Document document)
```